# create mysql table with one to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql

I already created two tables say `users` and `files`. The `users` table has fields: `user-id, username`. The `files` table has fields: `file-id, file-name and user-id.`

If I use this relation then we have one file item pointing to only one customer. I want to use an array of users in the files table. How do I store it in table?

Comment: You will need another table `users_files` to store that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need another table `users_files` with fields `user-id, file-id` to store that

Then you can insert as many users as you want for each file.

Use foreign keys to maintain integrity check

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I got the concept.